# White background when Android app start up

Tags: android, android-layout

Every when my app starts up, there's a white background displays in a short time.
Despite of using splash screen, the problem is still exists.
I would like to set the start up screen to black instead of white as default!

This is my splash's screen activity:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

private static String TAG = SplashActivity.class.getName();
private static long SLEEP_TIME = 1;    // Sleep for some time

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);    // Removes title bar
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    // Start timer and launch main activity
    IntentLauncher launcher = new IntentLauncher();
    launcher.start();
}

private class IntentLauncher extends Thread {

    /**
      * Sleep for some time and than start new activity.
      */ 
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Sleeping
            Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME*1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }

        // Start main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        SplashActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        SplashActivity.this.finish();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
}
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this tag in your manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

instead of :

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: Of all the answers this one is the only one that worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 31):

in styles.xml, in the theme specified in your AndroidManifest.xml, add the following line:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
```

Comment: What if I want an ImageView to be shown in this style?

Comment: This is what i was looking for.

Comment: had to extend `Activity` instead of `AppCompatActivity` and then set my theme's parent to `"android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar"` before this worked for me

Answer (score 6):

in drawable folder, create your own starting_screen.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <!-- black background -->
            <solid android:color="@color/colorBlack" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!-- launcher icon -->
    <item android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground" android:height="150dp" android:width="150dp" android:gravity="center" />
</layer-list>
```

then add this to your style

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/starting_screen</item>
```

now a black screen with your launcher icon will appear whenever you launch your application

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change the white screen that appears before splash screen to black just change the theme for the SplashActivity rather than for the entire app.

You can use this:

```
<activity
    android:name="your.package.SplashActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the starting window background color using a custom theme.  See [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

In styles.xml, theme applied for SplashActivity, add the following line

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
```

where @drawable/background is the background you applied for your Splash Screen or it could be any color you need.

Answer (score 0):

you have set splash.xml when your activity starts. change that, change the parent background to black or whichever color you wan. it will work, or change the splash.xml theme to holo_dark or any other theme