# android: setRequestedOrientation SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE. How to change background

Tags: android

I am having

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

So when i start the app, for a fraction of time it show white screen before and after rotating to landscape, and then the application starts.

How to change the color of the background shown before the activity starts

Comment: might be because your app is multidex and that white screen is shown while the app is being unpacked.

Comment: got the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738879/white-background-when-android-app-start-up. 
Add `<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>`